# Get all messages from rabbitMQ

Tags: javascript, async-await, rabbitmq, amqp, es6-promise

I'm trying to get all messages from rabbitMQ queue.

```
const messages = await rabbit.getMessages(outputQueue, false);
```

Here is realization of getMessages method. The problem is it processes only 3-5 messages and calling 'resolve'. Some time later it processes rest messages, but 'resolve' has already been called and it can't be executed again.

```
const amqp = require('amqplib');
.
.
let amqpUrl;
let queueConf;

const init = (connection, queue) => {
  amqpUrl =`amqp://${connection.user}:${connection.password}@${connection.host}:${connectio    n.port}`;
  if (connection.vhost) {
amqpUrl = `amqp://${connection.user}:${connection.password}@${connection.host}:${connection.port}/${connection.vhost}`;
  }
  queueConf = queue;
}

const getChannel = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  amqp.connect(amqpUrl).then((conn) => {
    conn.createChannel().then((ch) => {
      ch.prefetch(1000).then(() => resolve(ch))
    })
  })
})

module.exports = (connection, queue) => {
  init(connection, queue);
  return {
    getMessages: (queueName, cleanQueue) => new Promise((resolve) => {
      let messages = [];
      let i = 1;
      getChannel().then((ch) => {
        ch.consume(queueName, (msg) => {
          messages.push(msg);
          console.log(msg.content.toString())
        }, { noAck: cleanQueue }).then(() => {
          logger.info(`Retreived ${messages.length} messages from ${queueName}`);
          resolve(messages)
        })
      })
    })
    .
    .
    };
  };
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: proof that Promises aren't a solution for everything - and Promises definitely don't fit for this sort of thing

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this but it will be very slow and will possibly never resolve if messages are added to the queue faster than you can consume them. Essentially you keep getting one message at a time until [`channel.get()`](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_get) resolves with `false` instead of a message object:

```
getMessages: (queueName, cleanQueue) => {
  let messages = []
  let i = 1
  return getChannel().then(function getMessage (ch) {
    return ch.get(queueName, { noAck: cleanQueue }).then((msg) => {
      if (msg) {
        messages.push(msg)
        return getMessage(ch)
      } else {
        logger.info(`Retrieved ${messages.length} messages from ${queueName}`)
        return messages
      }
    })
  }).catch((err) => {
    err.consumedMessages = messages
    return Promise.reject(err)
  })
}
```